# Data wrangling for linear regression in r

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm attempting to run a linear regression in r using the lm() function but I get various errors however I change my data. I want to see if parental gender, child gender and parent score predict child score. My code is:

```
mod1 <- lm(score_child ~ score_parent*parent_child*female_male, data=dat, na.action = na.pass)
```

data currently looks something like this:

```
Subject   Family_number  female_male   parent_child  score_child   score_parent 
1         1               1             0             230           NA
2         1               0             1             NA            400
3         1               0             0             450           NA
4         2               1             1             NA            500
5         2               1             0             500           NA                
.
```

I understand this would be easier to do if the data was in long format however, as I need to separate child and parent score, I thought this was the best way. The NAs give me a lot of grief and I've tried every na.action command but I get errors such as Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'.

Would the beast approach be to change the NA command in lm(), change the layout of my data and if so, to what and how would I then specify child and parent score in lm()?

Bonus question; these children any parents are part of families and I would ideally like to analyse the data in family groups. Would that require one regression per family and if so, wouldn't that effect my confident interval?

My dissertation and myself would greatly appreciate any help!

Julia

Comment: In the data sample you show there is no observation without `NA` values. It's unclear how you expect a linear regression function to deal with that (hint: It can't).

Comment: Also, you probably need a different kind of analysis. You should talk to a local statistician.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to change the layout to make it work somehow. Thanks though!

Comment: You also have the problem that you are trying to predict `score_child` and some of those are `NA`. As a first step you need to filter out those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lm` requires that each unit be in one row, not spread over two rows.  Assuming that each unit consists of exactly one parent and one child and that the elements of each pair follow each other in adjacent rows in the data frame so that rows 1 and 2 form a unit, 3 and 4 form a unit and so on then we can extract the parent rows and child rows into `Parent` and `Child` data frames.  These will have the same number of rows so we can `cbind` them together and rationalize the column names of the combined data frame which will now have `nrow(DF)/2` rows.  Note that `DF2` shown later on below has no NA values.

```
Parent <- subset(DF, is.na(score_child))
Child <- subset(DF, is.na(score_parent))
DF2 <- cbind(
 with(Parent, data.frame(subj_parent = Subject, sex_parent = female_male, score_parent)),
 with(Child, data.frame(subj_child = Subject, sex_child = female_male, score_child))
)

lm(score_child ~ score_parent * sex_child * sex_parent, DF2)
```

`DF2` looks like this:

```
> DF2
  subject_parent sex_parent score_parent subject_child sex_child score_child
1              2          0          400             1         1         230
2              4          1          500             3         0         450
```

### Note

We assume that the input, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- "
Subject   female_male   parent_child  score_child   score_parent
1         1             0             230           NA
2         0             1             NA            400
3         0             0             450           NA
4         1             1             NA            500"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and for taking the time! However, some families have two parents and one child or two children and one parent. I've been told to run a mixed effect model to preserve family structure.

Comment: does Subject represent family?

Comment: As long as the data is in the form shown in the question with adjacent parent and child rows then the above still works.  That means that any child with two parents appears as two identical rows and any parent with two children appears as two identical rows.  If that is not the case then the question has not properly described the data and how one links a parent row to a child row.  Also whether you use mixed effect or fixed effects model has nothing to do with all this.

Comment: I've edited the dataset now. I thought it would be too complicated to add in the factor of family number but using mixed effects I can do that. Apologies for any confusion.